# c# how to make loading text simple

Tags: c#

This is all I got so far, everything will go good until it gets too the last string in the array

```
private static String[] loading = {"Loading.", "Loading..", "Loading..."};

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; loading.Length > i; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\r" + loading[i]);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhat simpler code. might be useful.used mod instead of resetting

```
 int i = 0;
 while (true)
 {
     i = i % 3;
     Console.Write("\r" + loading[i++]);
     Thread.Sleep(500);               
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look better if you write it in a single line:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int loadingLength = 5;
    Console.Write("Loading...");

    for (int i = 0; i < loadingLength; i++)
        Console.Write(".");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

If you still need to output many lines of "loading", think about generating string of dots of length N instead of storing them all in an array.
Tip: `new string(char, count)` generates string of length `count` using chars `char`.

Comment: I mean, how would I do this making it do, Loading. , Loading.., Loading... then after that,it goes back to the first one which would be loading.

Comment: @nooby Oh, just use `while` instead of `for`, and reset your `i` to 0 in the end of your array.